# Qual tecnologia usar para desenvolver um Webservices para Android

Tags: java, android, cloud

Estou iniciando no mundo Android e identifiquei que para a aplicação que estou projetando terei que seguir uma arquitetura WebServices usando um banco de dados em plataforma Cloud.

O banco de dados eu já defini que será MySQL. Já WebServices eu estou em dúvida se vou de Java ou .Net.

Olhando pelo lado de performance e custo, inclusive considerando a futura plataforma Cloud que terei que contratar (estou olhando UOL e Kinghost), vejo duas possibilidades:

- Criar os Webservices em Java para ter tudo em um Cloud sobre Linux
- Criar os WebServices em .Net para utilizar uma plataforma Windows

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de cada plataforma nesse contexto?

Comment: Marcio, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Compreendo que este seja o tipo de pergunta que nos surge quando começamos a desenvolver algo. No entanto, ela não se enquadra no escopo do site. Aqui as perguntas devem ser objectivas, sobre problemas de programação concretos. A sua pergunta originará resposta baseadas em opinião, algo que não é aceite aqui. Convido-o a ver como o site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e qual o [tipo de pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que se enquadra.

Comment: Ramaral, não entendi qual é o problema de respostas baseadas em opinião. Se eu quisesse uma resposta objetiva para um caso específico (problema técnico) eu teria perguntando de forma objetiva sobre o caso específico, mas essa não é minha necessidade, pois a intenção era mesmo saber a opinião dos profissionais que aqui participam frente a experiência que possuem no desenvolvimento de aplicações do tipo. Na minha opinião (sei que é proibido ter opinião aqui) é que essa restrição apenas limita a troca de experiências e de conhecimento, mas tudo bem, se é política do site então irei respeitar.

Comment: +1 Marcio. Acho que existem casos e casos @ramaral. E nesse caso uma resposta baseada na opinião e na experiência é a mais adequada para a pergunta do Marcio.

Comment: @Luiz A questão está em que, de acordo com as regras, tanto a pergunta como a resposta não deveriam ter ocorrido.

Comment: Marcio, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Editei sua resposta para evitar que ela seja muito opinativa. Dessa forma, acredito que seja possível responder de forma um pouco mais objetiva. Se não estiver contente, pode editar a pergunta novamente. Se tiver outras dúvidas, sugiro que vá criando perguntas diferentes, cada uma com um objetivo bem específico em mente. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

A verdade é que, do ponto de vista do App cliente, não faz diferença alguma em que tecnologia o Web Service é implementado. Esta é justamente a ideia de dos Web Services para começar.

Portanto, os fatores que podem levar à decisão de qual plataforma ou linguagem usar estão em outro lugar.

Alguns são...

## Dois ambientes diferentes?

A não ser que você já seja um desenvolvedor .Net proficiente, se você já desenvolve em Java para Android, usar a mesma linguagem no servidor faz mais sentido.

## Custo do servidor

A não ser que seja um projeto pessoal financiado do seu bolso e sem um retorno significativo, o custo da hospedagem não deve ser um problema.

Entretanto, saiba que para Java o custo inicial é maior, já que uma instância pequena de Java ocupa muita memória. A vantagem do Java é que a memória não é proporcional ao número de usuários.

Além disso, existem serviços como [OpenShift](http://openshift.com) que permitem um uso limitado gratuitamente.

## Outras alternativas

Por outro lado, se você quer manter um custo mínimo ou não conhece bem nem Java nem .Net e quer um ambiente mais simples, poderia usar inclusive PHP ou Node.js para desenvolver seus Web Services.

## Sistema operacional

O sistema operacional também não é importante no sentido de que ambos vão dar suporte.

Mas, em geral, o ambiente linux é mais flexível e leve. Existem distribuições feitas para uso na Nuvem que funcionam com pouca memória e pouco espaço de armazenamento.

O problema do Linux é que, caso você não esteja acostumado com esse tipo de ambiente e não domine o terminal, você pode facilmente perder muito tempo dando murro em ponto de faca até conseguir fazer coisas simples que, no Windows, poderia resolver em alguns minutos clicando em alguns menus.

Comment: utluiz, obrigado pelo retorno. Vou então partir para um ambiente Linux/Java/Mysql/Tomcat do lado do servidor WebServices/XML/Json, pois tenho maior proficiência em java/Linux uma vez que nunca programei em .NET. Quando eu precisar de algo para migração em produção irei pegar um plano cloud lá no Kinghost que a primeira vista atenderá minhas necessidades e tem bom preço. Com as respostas que tive aqui mais umas pesquisadas deu para fechar uma arquitetura que vai me atender e seja escalável com o tempo. Mais uma vez obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: +1 por salvar a pergunta antes de responder :)

Answer (score -4):

O WebService é pessoal tem que ser algo que atenda a sua necessidade com mais precisão, ou seja as duas opções são boas (Linux ou Windows). Isso é questão pessoal: facilidade pra você em desenvolver, preço, estabilidade, hospedagem etc.

Eu também aconselho a você dar uma olhada sobre WebService REST JSON, que é feito para aplicações que vão transportar dados não muito elevados, é rápido, fácil de utilizar e você poderá desenvolver em PHP sendo assim rodando em ambas as estruturas Linux ou Windows.

Uma dica: Se for transportar dados com muito conteúdos separados, utilize JSON ao invés de XML porque as tags do XML tornam muito grande o recebimento gastando assim mais processamento.

Comment: -1 Porque ao responder está incentivando perguntas que são fora do escopo do Stackoverflow.

Comment: Putz, Eu não sabia, Desculpe, Eu só queria ajudar, Poxa desnegativa aí.

Comment: Não tem que pedir desculpas. Sei que você só quis ajudar, mas é obrigação de cada um de nós zelar pelas regras do site.

Comment: -1 a resposta está completamente baseada em opinião.

Comment: Sim @DiegoFelipe, eu devia ter feito notar isso também.

Comment: Caraca vocês são bons para negativar heim, Onde fica a consideração? rsrs, Mas tá tranquilo. Talvez se negativassem menos e ajudasse mais a comunidade seria melhor.

Comment: Não se sinta visado, o que é levado em consideração é o conteúdo da resposta e não quem responde.

Comment: Viniam a intenção do -1 é avisar ao autor que a resposta/pergunta não está boa, que ele deve melhorá-la, não é pra penalizar você ou usuario qualquer que seja. É intessante que você tenha conhecimento do funcionamento do site e suas regras, tudo pode ser encontrado na [central da ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Viniam, obrigado pelo retorno e desculpe pelo problema que lhe causei ao me ajudar. Avaliando sua resposta, vi que outra opção é utilizar REST/Json que parece ser uma forma mais "econômica" de trafegar dados, eu estava só com WebServices na cabeça e sua resposta me fez considerar outra alternativa. Estou com algumas dúvidas mas me limito a não perguntar já que provavelmente irão se enquadrar em opinião, mas por fim, vou dar mais uma estudada e detalhar mais a arquitetura linux/mysql/webservices java/rest/json que provavelmente irá me atender. Mais uma vez, obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Viniam, 3 dicas para evitar esse tipo de negativo, mesmo quando é algo que envolve opinião. Primeiro, evite simplesmente dizer "isso é questão pessoal", pois mesmo que seja, cada decisão envolve fatores positivos e negativos, vantagens e desvantagens que são relativamente objetivos, então seria útil se falasse sobre alguns desses aspectos. Segundo, ao invés de simplesmente dizer que se pode usar ou fazer isso ou aquilo, tente embasar sua opinião em termos mais técnicos, mais uma vez focando nas vantagens e desvantagens. Terceiro, formate melhor sua resposta, tem 3 ideias em um só parágrafo.

Comment: Eu tinha até negativado mas mudei de idéia, achei que dar uma formatação mais profissional no texto alivia um pouco o problema

Comment: ps: bons pra negativar e pra positivar também, esses seus 300 pontos não vieram do nada :P

Comment: Uma dica, remova a resposta que os negativos deixam de ser contados na sua reputação.

Comment: Os +3 no meu primeiro comentário obrigam-me a esclarecer que responder a uma pergunta "baseada em opinião", só por si, não justifica dar -1. O que quis realçar é que respostas do tipo desta, que opinam sem dar justificação, incentivam a que hajam outras, tornando o poste como se de um *forum* se tratasse. Nunca daria -1 à resposta do utiliz.